# sed: can't read /etc/dbus-1/session.conf: Input/output error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, sed, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Following a guide on ZDNet [here](http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-run-run-the-native-ubuntu-desktop-on-windows-10/#comments-917a78f3-dd3b-4e84-978c-152d7c1694a2), I have been trying to get ubuntu desktop working on Windows 10. though one line of code has been giving me trouble.

```
    sudo sed -i 's/<listen>.*<\/listen>/<listen>tcp:host=localhost,port=0<\/listen>/' /etc/dbus-1/session.conf
```

was returning "can't read /etc/dbus-1/session.conf file or directory not found.

So I found a "/etc/dbus-1/session.conf" file online and added it. Restarted the bash and it found it, but this time:

sed: can't read /etc/dbus-1/session.conf: Input/output error

is what i get.

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging. It dawned on me.

```
sudo touch session.conf
sudo vi session.conf
```

(paste in the conf file text I found [here](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/trusty/main/i386/dbus/1.6.18-0ubuntu4/file/etc/dbus-1/session.conf) and save

```
    sudo sed -i 's/<listen>.*<\/listen>/<listen>tcp:host=localhost,port=0<\/listen>/' /etc/dbus-1/session.conf
```

And it worked! Now I get to try to figure out why i am seeing
" Error: Error creating directory "/home/username/.cache/compizconfig-1" "

Comment: Did you actually solve the problem?

Comment: I solved the input/output error, (The issue was likely that I downloaded the file in a windows format and tried reading it with a Linux system. Only thing I could think of.) But the compizconfig issue is still causing problems I believe. I can open the UI settings. But when I try to launch the desktop, I get stuck at a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked quite a while ago, but for posterity I will point out that according to this [issue](https://github.com/QMonkey/wsl-tutorial/issues/3#issuecomment-390721585), it's been relocated to:

```
/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf
```